# wpa_supplicant.conf in raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, wifi, security

In order to have my raspberry pi access using ssh (on wifi) i

- Created a wpa_supplicant.conf file with necessary details
- Created an empty file 'ssh'

My question was around security. Is it secure to let the wpa_supplicant.conf file there while the raspberry pi is serving some traffic, since the wifi network password is in there?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by ` let the wpa_supplicant.conf file there while the raspberry pi is serving some traffic`. Where is that exactly? Keep in mind that the file will be moved from the boot partition to the root partition when booting the Pi with the card (and before wifi is activated).

Comment: You can also use `wpa_passphrase` to generate the hashed version of your WiFi password so it's not there in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Roger Jones commented: You don't need to store the wifi password as plain text. It's best practice to store it as encrypted pre-shared key. Your conf file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` should look like this:

```
network={
    ssid="YourSSID"
    psk="YourPlainTextPassword"
}
```

Run `wpa_passphrase "YourSSID"` in a terminal and you should be asked for the password. Enter it and copy the encrypted PSK (it looks like gibberish, i.e. `4eab908e8f2b644a335c173e0f33d3864cb00cb5311434d6275592ed2cf6af0d`).

Then open the conf file in an editor, i.e.:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

To play it safe:

Uncomment the psk line: `#psk="YourPlainTextPassword"`

Insert a new line: `psk=4eab908e8f2b644a335c173e0f33d3864cb00cb5311434d6275592ed2cf6af0d`

Save the conf file and reboot.

If your wifi connection still works fine, edit the conf file again and delete the line with the commented plain text password. Save the conf file and done!

Answer (score 1):

The default way to protect password containing files on unix is to restrict read and write access only to root so nobody else can read this file. In your case you should do if not already done:

```
rpi ~$ sudo chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Few hints:

**1.** `wpa_passphrase "YourSSID"` will not work if you have `!` or spaces in the SSID. So use simple quotes (`'`) here.

**2.** I found there was added a `wpa_supplicant.conf.save` with still the plain old data.

So make sure to delete this as well.

Comment: That seems to be a comment to another answer.

Comment: no, thats exactly the extension to the above statement.